# Typescript intellisense in vs code is not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I was installing couple of typings for my node server and suddenly the intellisense stopped working.

Here is how my tsconfig.json looks:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-p", "."],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc",
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "buildOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "removeComments": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": false,
        "target": "es5",
        "noResolve": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings"
    ]
}
```

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick tip: You might want to enable the TypeScript log so that it tracks errors in the TypeScript Service that is used by Visual Studio Code to power the TypeScript language features. On Windows, you have to set the "TSS_LOG" environment variable to "-level verbose" and I guess that it will be similar on Linux. Afterwards, the log might give you a hint what went wrong. There were already several instances where entries in the tsconfig.json had caused issues for newer versions of the TS Service.